# User with low reputation shows as having modified thread

Tags: support, reputation, edits

How can this user https://stackoverflow.com/users/196103/jan, reputation 3, show in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access as having "modified 7 hours ago", but on the modified thread, [How to get the name of Constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899655/how-to-get-the-name-of-constraint), not show at all?

This user also has two medals, which is somewhat puzzling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The user posted an answer and then deleted it.

If you have over 10K rep, you can see the deleted answer.

The badges aren't particularly surprising - they're Scholar and Editor. The user has made an edit, and accepted their own answer to a question.