# Incorrect user showing in most recently modified spot

Tags: support, bug

While browsing the list of unanswered questions over on Arqade, I came across this little gem:

[image]

Clicking on [the original question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/308069/53249) revealed that there were no edits or answers from anyone.

You can still view this live on [the list of unanswered questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers), and I imagine it will stay there until someone edits or answers the question.

#### Steps to reproduce:

- Find a question on the home page
- Post an answer so abysmal that it is immediately deleted
- Go back to the home page, and find the original question in the list
- Notice that your user name is still alive and well in the recently modified spot!

[Perhaps a 10K user can shed some light on this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/29091/365152), and maybe this is behavior is intentional, but it appears to be a (slight) bug in how thread modifications are shown on dashboards.

*(As noted in comments, if the user was deleted, the Community user should replace their user card. The user shown here is unregistered, and their account has not been deleted.)*

Comment: It's most likely caching.

Comment: I believe this is intentional, for the most part. However, if the account is deleted, it should change to show that the Community user performed the activity. Could be a caching bug?

Comment: Caching? The thread was last modified over 12 months ago.

Comment: The account isn't deleted.

Comment: Looks like this is an unregistered user who bumped the thread, and then had their answer deleted. That would make this a duplicate of [Remou's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29090/365152).

Comment: [Ninja Bumping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54868/282094) 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal. If the most recent activity on a question is that an answer is deleted, the activity changes from "answered ... [username]" to "modified ... [username]". That's what you're seeing there - there's a deleted junk answer.

This happens whether the answer was deleted by the poster themselves or the community through flags or delete votes. If the account is deleted in addition, the modified action will be attributed to the Community user.

I've cleared the username to the default since there's no reason for that particular one to show up anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. It is helpful to have support for removing that particular username from being so visible on the dashboards. As this is otherwise normal system behavior, I am voting to close this question as a duplicate of an earlier (similar) question.